# Composable atomic-like operations

Tags: haskell, transactions, atomic

I want to compose operations that may fail, but there is a way to roll back.

For example - an external call to book a hotel room, and an external call to charge a credit card. Both of those calls may fail such as no rooms left, invalid credit card. Both have ways to roll back - cancel hotel room, cancel credit charge.

1. Is there a name for this type of (not real) atomic. Whenever i search for haskell transaction, I get `STM`.
2. Is there an abstraction, a way to compose them, or a library in haskell or any other language?

I feel you could write a monad `Atomic T` which will track these operations and roll them back if there is an exception.

Edit:

These operations may be `IO` operations. If the operations were only memory operations, as the two answers suggest, STM would suffice.

For example booking hotels would via HTTP requests. Database operations such as inserting records via socket communication.

In the real world, for irreversible operations there is a grace period before the operation will be done - e.g. credit cards payments and hotel bookings may be settled at the end of the day, and therefore it is fine to cancel before then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to resort to making your own monad, it will look something like this:

```
import Control.Exception (onException, throwIO)

newtype Rollbackable a = Rollbackable (IO (IO (), a))

runRollbackable :: Rollbackable a -> IO a
runRollbackable (Rollbackable m) = fmap snd m
    -- you might want this to catch exceptions and return IO (Either SomeException a) instead

instance Monad Rollbackable where
    return x = Rollbackable $ return (return (), x)
    Rollbackable m >>= f
       = do (rollback, x) <- m
            Rollbackable (f x `onException` rollback)
```

(You will probably want `Functor` and `Applicative` instances also, but they're trivial.)

You would define your rollbackable primitive actions in this way:

```
rollbackableChargeCreditCard :: CardNumber -> CurrencyAmount -> Rollbackable CCTransactionRef
rollbackableChargeCreditCard ccno amount = Rollbackable
   $ do ref <- ioChargeCreditCard ccno amount
        return (ioUnchargeCreditCard ref, ref)

ioChargeCreditCard :: CardNumber -> CurrencyAmount -> IO CCTransactionRef
-- use throwIO on failure
ioUnchargeCreditCard :: CCTransactionRef -> IO ()
-- these both just do ordinary i/o
```

Then run them like so:

```
runRollbackable
   $ do price <- rollbackableReserveRoom roomRequirements when
        paymentRef <- rollbackableChargeCreditCard ccno price
        -- etc
```

Answer (score 6):

This is exactly the purpose of STM. Actions are composed so that they succeed or fail together, automatically.

Very similar to your hotel room problem is the bank transaction example in Simon Peyton-Jones's chapter in "Beautiful Code": http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/stm/beautiful.pdf

Comment: Ah, but STM specifically prohibits IO.  This question asks about IO actions that can be reversed if necessary with a second IO action.

Comment: STM is very compatible with IO actions - it just doesn't perform them directly (http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/software-transactional-memory.html). Not all IO *can* be transactional - there's no `rollback` action for `launchMissiles`

Comment: I don't see that the question specifically mentions `IO`.  But in any case, the answer for `IO` is that it can't be done, because the `IO` monad has operations that irrevocably destroy information, and no way to duplicate the state.  In fact, the `IO` monad is designed specifically for that!

Answer (score 1):

If your computations could be done only with `TVar` like things then `STM` is perfect.

If you need a side effect (like "charge Bob $100") and if there is a error later issue a retraction (like "refund Bob $100") then you need, drumroll please: [Control.Exceptions.bracketOnError](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Exception.html#v%3abracketOnError)

```
bracketOnError
        :: IO a         -- ^ computation to run first (\"acquire resource\")
        -> (a -> IO b)  -- ^ computation to run last (\"release resource\")
        -> (a -> IO c)  -- ^ computation to run in-between
        -> IO c         -- returns the value from the in-between computation
```

> Like `Control.Exception.bracket`, but only performs the final action if there was an
>   exception raised by the in-between computation.

Thus I could imagine using this like:

```
let safe'charge'Bob = bracketOnError (charge'Bob) (\a -> refund'Bob)

safe'charge'Bob $ \a -> do
   rest'of'transaction
   which'may'throw'error
```

Make sure you understand where to use the `Control.Exception.mask` operation if you are in a multi-threaded program and try things like this.

And I should emphasize that you can and should read the Source Code to [Control.Exception](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Control-Exception.html) and [Control.Exception.Base](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Control-Exception-Base.html) to see how this is done in GHC.

Comment: One uses Control.Exception.throwIO inside the transaction to force it to roll back.  One needs to wrap (safe'charge ...) in something to actually catch the exception (catch*, handle*, try*).

Answer (score 0):

You really can do this with the clever application of STM. The key is to separate out the IO parts. I assume the trouble is that a transaction might appear to succeed initially, and fail only later on. (If you can recognize failure right away, or soon after, things are simpler):

```
main = do
   r   <- reserveHotel
   c   <- chargeCreditCard

   let room         = newTVar r
       card         = newTVar c
       transFailure = newEmptyTMVar

   rollback <- forkIO $ do 
       a <- atomically $ takeTMVar transFailure --blocks until we put something here
       case a of
         Left  "No Room"       -> allFullRollback
         Right "Card declined" -> badCardRollback

  failure <- listenForFailure -- A hypothetical IO action that blocks, waiting for
                              -- a failure message or an "all clear"
  case failures of
      "No Room"       -> atomically $ putTMVar (Left "No Room")
      "Card Declined" -> atomically $ putTMVar (Right "Card declined")
      _               -> return ()
```

Now, there's nothing here that MVars couldn't handle: all we're doing is forking a thread to wait and see if we need to fix things. But you'll presumably be doing some other stuff with your card charges and hotel reservations...

Comment: Is it possible to run forkIO (or any IO) from STM?

Comment: No. But most of the time the above code is in `IO`, not `STM`. When you need to be in `STM` for a while, you just use `atomically`.